# EsHadoopInvalidRequest: [POST]

Tags: java, hadoop, elasticsearch, apache-spark

Hello I am trying to read data from ElasticSearch. My Code is as follows,

```
SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf()
        .setAppName("Spark ES Integration").setMaster("local");
// .set("spark.ui.port", "7077");
sparkConf.set("es.nodes", "xx.xx.xx.xx");
sparkConf.set("es.port", "9200");
sparkConf.set("es.resource", "blog/post");
sparkConf.set("es.query", "?q=user:dilbert");
JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);

JavaPairRDD<String, Map<String, Object>> esRDD = JavaEsSpark.esRDD(sc);
System.out.println("**********" + esRDD.count()); // Prints 1 - Only one record is present
System.out.println("**********" + esRDD.first()); // Throws exception
```

Program outputs count correctly but throws exception when first record fetched from RDD.
Why request is of type POST when I just want to read the data?
What is wrong here? Query mentioned in configuration executes correctly.

Exception is

> org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.EsHadoopInvalidRequest: [POST] on [blog/post/_search?search_type=scan&scroll=5m&size=50&preference=_shards:0;_only_node:03oYNb7BTjG2vOzo9lSnzQ] failed; server[null] returned [400|Bad Request:]
>   .
>   .
>   3091 [Executor task launch worker-0] ERROR org.apache.spark.executor.Executor - Exception in task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
>   org.apache.spark.util.TaskCompletionListenerException: [POST] on [blog/post/_search?search_type=scan&scroll=5m&size=50&preference=_shards:0;_only_node:03oYNb7BTjG2vOzo9lSnzQ] failed; server[null] returned [400|Bad Request:]
>   .
>   .
>   3099 [task-result-getter-0] WARN  org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager - Lost task

Comment: Which connector are you using?

Comment: ElasticSearch version is 1.7 
ES-Hadoop version is 2.2.0